# Adobe illustrator generated images have un-expected size?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What I want to do is to generate an image of a specific size, for example `w=44mm, h=18mm`, and save it with `300 ppi` in PNG or JPG format.

The problem is, now I have the PNG or JPG image file on my mac, when I open it with Preview, I found that the image size is far bigger than `w=44m, h=18mm`.

So why the saved image is not the size specified in Illustrator?

**Update**
In Preview, I found these settings,
[image]

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions in Preview? I bet it's about 1200x1200px.

Comment: @Scott, I updated the post with the settings I found in Preview.

Comment: Yuour measuring the object but exporting the wite area too

Comment: @joojaa, really? I don't think so, since I selected the blue rectangle (at the center of white background).

Comment: @avocado but the export is set to export the artboard?

Comment: @joojaa, no, the export only gives the blue rectangle as the whole image, not including the white background.

Comment: Err 1.73 inches is  43.942 mm and 0.71 inches is 18.034 mm Which seems to be exactly the  dimensions in illustrator. Preview just has a 2 decimal precision. And offcourse you can only have full pixels

Comment: @joojaa, I updated the post with how I exported the image.

Comment: @joojaa, sorry I don't understand *you can only have full pixels*.

Comment: Jpeg is a matrix of pixels. You can not have partial pixels you either have a full row of pixels or you do not. this means that your output is off by 0-2/300 inches every time you do the export. BUt then preview is only telling you sizes with 2 decimals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong here.

- 44mm = 1.732"
- 18mm = 0.709"
- 1.732*300dpi=519.6 - rounded up to 520px
- 0.709*300dpi=212.7 - rounded up to 213px

Rounding is necessary because pixels must be whole numbers, not fractions.

So working back the size from whole pixels, we get the following:

- 520/300 = 1.7333 - rounded to 2 decimal places = 1.73"
- 213/300 = 0.71"

This matches the size exactly as shown in your Preview application.